# Do I need to close the connection

Tags: java, spring

Whether the `JdbcDaoSupport#getConnection()` new a connection or just get the connection from the pool?

Answer (score 2):

It returns a new one as the [Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/support/JdbcDaoSupport.html#getConnection%28%29) states, consider usign a conection pool, take a look [here](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/PoolableConnection.html)

Another relevant [thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?16853-Close-connection-when-using-JDBCDAOSupport-MappingSqlQuery)

Comment: Thanks for your help @O.D , at first I using org.apache.commons.dbcp to create cp ,but something wrong with it to execute sybase proc , so I try to using primitive jdbc to execute the proc

Answer (score 0):

You should call [releaseConnection()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/support/JdbcDaoSupport.html#releaseConnection%28java.sql.Connection%29), inside it will close the connection if need.